# "encrypt" and "encryptionalgorithm " not working for Coldfusion 11

Tags: encryption, coldfusion, cfmail, coldfusion-11

There are two new attributes are added to cfmail in Coldfusion 11 named "encrypt" and "encryptionalgorithm ". But they are not working. When I am sending normal email it is successful on my local system but with encryption it fails.

```
 <cfmail    server="smtp.gmail.com"  
            username="deepakkumarpadhy631@gmail.com"
            password="*****" port="465" usessl="true"
            from="deepakkumarpadhy631@gmail.com" 
            to="dkumar431@gmail.com"
            subject="Test Email" 
            type="text/html"
            encrypt = "true" 
            encryptionalgorithm = "Standard"  >
        #emailTxt#
</cfmail>
```

Anyone faced the same issue?

Comment: Can you quantify what you mean by "fails"? Also, anything going into any log files?

Comment: @AdamCameron: It is there on the undelivered mail list

Comment: Yes in the mail log I found: `coldfusion.mail.MailImpl$RecipientCertificateException: The recipient certificate is not specified. ` So I think recipientcert is also required.

Comment: Yeah, the docs def aren't clear there, but it will be the case. I'll hit up the Adobe guys to improve the docs. Once you get it working, make sure to post an answer for the next person having the problem, yeah?

Comment: Frank from Adobe is on the case with the docs.

Comment: Frank advises he's updated the docs: https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/cfmail